# Using Form Authentication for generate jwt

Tags: jwt

I have 2 projects that are **WebApp** and **Api** both use net core.
In the **WebApp**, I write a method Login that use identity and the **Api** project has method Get to get data from database.

So can I use the Login method in **WebApp** to generate JWT after user login to authorize to call Get method from **API** via ajax ?

PS: Sorry for my English

Thanks

Comment: Sure you can. You might also want to look into OAuth2.

Comment: Yes you can, you just need  to share the JWT secret between the **WebApp** and **Api** to make sure that the JWT is generated and verified with the same secret key

Comment: could anyone show me the example for clearly understanding

Comment: Thank everyone, I did it.